# How can I make an alias to a non-function member attribute in a Python class?

Tags: python, class, alias

I'm in the midst of writing a Python library API and I often run into the scenario where my users want multiple different names for the same functions and variables.

If I have a Python class with the function `foo()` and I want to make an alias to it called `bar()`, that's super easy:

```
class Dummy:
   
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def foo(self):
      pass

   bar = foo
```

Now I can do this with no problem:

```
d = Dummy()
d.foo()
d.bar()
```

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to do this with a class attribute that is a regular variable (e.g. a string) rather than a function?  If I had this piece of code:

```
d = Dummy()
print(d.x)
print(d.xValue)
```

I want `d.x` and `d.xValue` to always print the same thing. If `d.x` changes, it should change `d.xValue` also (and vice-versa).

I can think of a number of ways to do this, but none of them seem as smooth as I'd like:

- Write a custom annotation
- Use the `@property` annotation and mess with the setter
- Override the `__setattr__` class functions

Which of these ways is best?  Or is there another way? I can't help but feel that if it's so easy to make aliases for functions, it should be just as easy for arbitrary variables...

Comment: Consider: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." -- The Zen of Python

Comment: Why do your users want this bad bad thing?

Comment: It's mostly because my scripting API is used across multiple subsystems & domains, so the default vocabulary changes.  What's known as "X" in one domain is known as "Y" in another domain.  Also, because they're bad human beings. :-)

Comment: @BrentWritesCode can you change the accepted answer please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can provide a [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) and [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) that reference an aliases map:

```
class Dummy:
    aliases = {
        'xValue': 'x',
        'another': 'x',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 17

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        name = self.aliases.get(name, name)
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "aliases":
            raise AttributeError  # http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html
        name = self.aliases.get(name, name)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


d = Dummy()
assert d.x == 17
assert d.xValue == 17
d.x = 23
assert d.xValue == 23
d.xValue = 1492
assert d.x == 1492
```

Comment: Thanks for http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html
; it's a very interesting read!

Comment: That's something close to what I was picturing, though I didn't come up with the alias dictionary the first time around. That makes for a nice way to avoid if/else ladders and long, verbose setattr/getattr functions.

Comment: Important Addendum:  Using `getattr` inside of `__getattr__` actually causes an infinite recursion for non-existent attribtues (e.g. for the example above, try doing `print d.asdf`). I believe using `object.__getattribute__` instead solves the problem.

Comment: @Brent: ouch, that was a bad mistake on my part.  Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Am I missing something important? Why can't he simply make the attributes properties and then alias them as he would the methods, as in my answer below? I'm asking earnestly, because if there is a subtle difference in result, I would love to understand it.

Answer (score 31):

This can be solved in exactly the same way as with class methods. For example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 17

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, inp):
        self._x = inp

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x

    # Alias
    xValue = x

d = Dummy()
print(d.x, d.xValue)
#=> (17, 17)
d.x = 0
print(d.x, d.xValue)
#=> (0, 0)
d.xValue = 100
print(d.x, d.xValue)
#=> (100, 100)
```

The two values will always stay in sync. You write the actual property code with the attribute name you prefer, and then you alias it with whatever legacy name(s) you need.

Comment: Works a treat and seems a whole lot simpler to me.

Comment: If you only need one alias, you don't need a separate `_x` property. You could just do `self.x = 17` and then define `xValue` as the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 6):

What are you going to do when half your users decide to use `d.x` and the other half `d.xValue`? What happens when they try to share code? Sure, it will work, *if you know all the aliases*, but will it be obvious? Will it be obvious to you when you put away your code for a year?

In the end, I think this kind of niceness or luxury is an evil trap that will eventually cause more confusion than good.

---

> It's mostly because my scripting API
>   is used across multiple subsystems &
>   domains, so the default vocabulary
>   changes. What's known as "X" in one
>   domain is known as "Y" in another
>   domain.

You could make aliases with properties this way:

```
class Dummy(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.x=1
   @property
   def xValue(self):
      return self.x
   @xValue.setter
   def xValue(self,value):
      self.x=value

d=Dummy()
print(d.x)
# 1
d.xValue=2
print(d.x)
# 2
```

But for the reasons mentioned above, I don't think this is a good design.  It
makes Dummy harder to read, understand and use. For each user you've doubled the
size of the API the user must know in order to understand Dummy.

A better alternative is to use the [Adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Python_2).
This allows you to keep Dummy nice, compact, succinct:

```
class Dummy(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.x=1
```

While those users in the subdomain who wish to use a different vocabulary can do so
by using an Adaptor class:

```
class DummyAdaptor(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.dummy=Dummy()
   @property
   def xValue(self):
      return self.dummy.x
   @xValue.setter
   def xValue(self,value):
      self.dummy.x=value
```

For each method and attribute in Dummy, you simply hook up similar methods and properties
which delegate the heavy lifting to an instance of Dummy.

It might be more lines of code, but it will allow you to preserve a clean design for Dummy, easier to maintain, document, and unit test. People will write code that makes sense because the class will restrict what API is available, and there will be only one name for each concept given the class they've chosen.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with you, but I've fought that battle and lost.  The next best thing I can do is try to implement & document it well so it's as clear as it can be a year from now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some of ideas shown in the ActiveState Python recipe titled [*Caching and aliasing with descriptors*](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/276643-caching-and-aliasing-with-descriptors/?in=user-1732285). Here's a concise version of the code shown there which provides the functionality you seek.

**Edit:** A class containing `Alias` attributes could be made to automatically delete any associated target attributes when you `del` one (and vice-versa). The code for my answer now illustrates one easy way this could be done using a convenient class decorator which adds a custom `__delattr__()` to do the specialized deletion management when attribute `Alias's` could be involved.

```
class Alias(object):
    """ Descriptor to give an attribute another name. """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None:
            return self  # a class attribute reference, return this descriptor
        return getattr(inst, self.name)
    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        setattr(inst, self.name, value)
    def __delete__(self, inst):
        delattr(inst, self.name)


def AliasDelManager(cls):
    """ Class decorator to auto-manage associated Aliases on deletion. """
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        """ Deletes any Aliases associated with a named attribute, or
            if attribute is itself an Alias, deletes the associated target.
        """
        super(cls, self).__delattr__(name) # Use base class' method.
        for attrname in dir(self):
            attr = getattr(cls, attrname)
            if isinstance(attr, Alias) and attr.name == name:
                delattr(cls, attrname)

    setattr(cls, '__delattr__', __delattr__)
    return cls


if __name__=='__main__':
    @AliasDelManager
    class Dummy(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 17
        xValue = Alias('x')  # create an Alias for attr 'x'

    d = Dummy()
    assert d.x == 17
    assert d.xValue == 17
    d.x = 23
    assert d.xValue == 23
    d.xValue = 1492
    assert d.x == 1492
    assert d.x is d.xValue
    del d.x  # should also remove any associated Aliases
    assert 'xValue' not in dir(d)
    print('done - no exceptions were raised')
```

Comment: That is really clever. The only thing that bugs me about it is that if I do `del d.x` and then do `dir(d)`, `xValue` will still show up in the resulting list.

Comment: @Brent Nash: I've added a class decorator to deal with the attribute deletion issue you pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

This function takes a attribute name as a param and return a property that work as an alias for getting and setting.

```py
def alias_attribute(field_name: str) -> property:
    """
    This function takes the attribute name of field to make a alias and return
    a property that work to get and set.
    """
    field = property(lambda self: getattr(self, field_name))
    field = field.setter(lambda self, value: setattr(self, field_name, value))
    return field
```

Example:

```py
>>> class A:
...     name_alias = alias_attribute('name')
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
... a = A('Pepe')

>>> a.name
'Pepe'

>>> a.name_alias
'Pepe'

>>> a.name_alias = 'Juan'

>>> a.name
'Juan'
```

Answer (score -2):

Override the `__getattr__()` method and return the appropriate value.

Comment: I don't think I see how just overriding `__getattr__` is going to solve the problem of propagating changes when the user says `d.x=5` versus `d.xValue=6`

Comment: You never mentioned anything about *setting* `d.xValue`. When they ask for the value of `d.xValue`, just look up and return `d.x` instead.

Comment: The original questions says `If d.x changes, it should change d.xValue also (and vice-versa).` I was trying to get at the fact that I wanted to be able to do `d.x=5` or `d.xValue=5`.  Apologies if I was unclear.