# Pythonic alias for instance variable?

Tags: python, properties, alias

I have a class in which I store data in a list for inheritance reasons. I would like to know, and I have done my share of googling, is there a cleaner way other than creating getter/setter functions and properties to give a alias to the element in this list?

For example...

```
class Serializable(object):
    """Adds serialization to from binary string"""

    def encode(self):
        """Pack into struct"""
        return self.encoder.pack(*self)

    def decode(self, data_str):
        """Unpack from struct"""
        self.data = self.encoder.unpack(data_str)
        return self.data


class Ping(Serializable):

    encoder = Struct("!16sBBBL")

    def __init__(self, ident=create_id(), ttl=TTL, hops=0, length=0):
        self.data = [ident, 1, ttl, hops, length]
        self.ident = property(self.data[0])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    @property
    def ident(self):
        return self.data[0]

    @ident.setter
    def ident(self, value):
        self.data[0] = value

    @property
    def protocol(self):
        return self.data[1]

    @protocol.setter
    def protocol(self, protocol):
        self.data[1]
```

I would prefer a more compact solution to reference object.ident while maintaining the ability to pack and unpack as above.

Comment: Would not be an issue at all but I am going to be further subclassing Ping many times and adding members.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I formatted your code for you (the "{}" button). The first reformat is free ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Johnsyweb won't let it happen again :)

Comment: This does not answer the question you asked, but it may solve your problem: don't write your own serialisation, use [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Can I define how the data is serialized via pickle? I have to follow a n already defined binary format.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017572/how-can-i-make-an-alias-to-a-non-function-member-attribute-in-a-python-class) had a workable elegant solution. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Beware of the function call to `create_id` on the method definition - this function willbe called only once, when the class is parsed, not at each invocation of the `__init__` method

Comment: @GeraldStephanRunionII: as for defining how it is done via Pickle: no - you can customize a lot of things about pickling and unpiclking, but you give the pickle protocol a dictionary, or other standard data type, that is then further serialized (and tehre are some etxra markups on the pickled string to mark object start, and so on, one has no control about)

Answer (score 3):

If you store your values/properties in a dictionary instead:

```
def __init__(self, ident=create_id(), ttl=TTL, hops=0, length=0):
    self.data = {
        'ident': ident,
        'protocol': 1,
        'ttl': hops,
        'length': length,
    }
```

And then override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return self.data[attr]
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr == 'data':
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
    else:
        self.data[attr] = value
```

Now you can do this:

```
>>> ping = Ping()
>>> ping.protocol
1
>>> ping.protocol = 2
>>> ping.protocol
2
```

If `self.data` absolutely has to be a list, you can do this instead:

```
class Ping(Serializable):

    mapping = ('ident', 'protocol', 'ttl', 'hops', 'length')

    encoder = Struct("!16sBBBL")

    def __init__(self, ident=create_id(), ttl=TTL, hops=0, length=0):
        self.data = [ident, 1, ttl, hops, length]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        index = self.mapping.index(attr)
        return self.data[index]

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr == 'data':
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        else:
            index = self.mapping.index(attr)
            self.data[index] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def alias_property(key):
    return property(
        lambda self: getattr(self, key),
        lambda self, val: setattr(self, key, val),
        lambda self: delattr(self, key))

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    prop_alias = alias_property('prop')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just shorten the code to access `ident`, you may just use "property" in the "old style" - that is, you pass to it, as parameters, the getter and setter functions, instead of using it as a decorator.

In this case, the functions are so small, they can be lambda functions, without affecting code readbility.

```
class Ping(Serializable):

    encoder = Struct("!16sBBBL")

    def __init__(self, ident=None, ttl=TTL, hops=0, length=0):
        if ident is None:
            ident = create_id()
        self.data = [ident, 1, ttl, hops, length]
        # The line bellow looks like garbage -
        # it does not even make sense as a call to `property`
        # should have a callable as first parameter
        # returns an object that is designed to work as a class attribute
        # self.ident = property(self.data[0])
        # rather:
        self.ident = ident 
        # this will use the property defined bellow

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    ident = property(lambda s: s.data[0], lambda s, v: s.data[0].__setitem__(0, v)
    protocol = property(lambda s: s.data[1], lambda s, v: s.data[1].__setitem__(1, v)
```

Comment: This is a nice succinct solution. Yes the property had to go. I am going with the previous solution and moving the __getattr__ __setattr__, and __getitem__ to my Serializable base class. All subclasses will be very brief.